# passing a target to the js link() method

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, target

How do I pass a target, _blank, to the js [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) method?

```
x = "my link to google"
x.link("www.google.com")

<a href="www.google.com">my link to google</a>
```

if its not possible is there an alternative method I could use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't; the `String.link` method is ancient and mostly deprecated. Construct the link using DOM methods instead:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com/");
link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode("my link to google"));
...
// this, or whatever else you want to do to add it to the document:
document.getElementById("something").appendChild(link);
```

Either that, or just build up the string yourself. `String.link` isn't doing much anyway.

Comment: `href` and `target` are both properties of `link`.  I prefer the `link.href = "http://www.google.com"` syntax over using `.setAttribute()`.  But, I suppose that's just a style preference.

Comment: createTextNode not createTextElement

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it with `link` method you can use `replace`:

```
.replace('a href=', 'a target="_blank" href=');
```