# Why aren't my links clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitch

I'm making a program that determines whether or not a Twitchtv user is currently streaming, and that offers a link to their page. The streaming portion is going fine, but nothing happens upon clicking their name. I can tell that it's a valid URL, because the page comes up if you drag the hyperlink to an empty tab, but it's still not clickable. I'm really baffled because I've done similar projects where the links are clickable without issue. Code is below, any help is appreciated.

### HTML:

```
<div>
    <section class='body'></section>
</div>
```

### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var members = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"],
        body1 = $('.body'),
        str = members[3],
        result = str.link("https://www.twitch.tv/" + str);
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp', function(data) {
        if (data.stream === null) {
            body1.append(result + ":" + "not currently streaming on Twitchtv.");
        }
        else body1.append(result + ":" + "currently streaming on Twitchtv.");
    });
})
```

Comment: what is str.link? you need to add an href to it...

Comment: I don't see any links here...

Comment: @JordanHendrix, [String.prototype.link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link)

Comment: I thought String.prototype.link was from the dark days...

Comment: @gcampbell https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link

Comment: result = str.link("https://www.twitch.tv/" + str); I've used .link before and it's worked.

Comment: Where did you test this code out? If you tested it on JSFiddle (I did at https://jsfiddle.net/ha7dtrwa/) it only fails because the HTML is inside a frame, and Twitch sends an `X-Frame-Options` header that prevents framing.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've been using Codepen. That's also where I've had .link work on a previous project.

Comment: @eversomber Check your browser console after clicking the link. You'll find it says something like `Refused to display 'https://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`.

Comment: @SpYk3HH oops, I was getting mixed up with [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#HTML_wrapper_methods).

Comment: @gcampbell I don't blame you. Been doing webdev since the late 1990s and never saw `Str.link()`.

Answer (score 3):

Twitch.tv sends a `X-Frame-Options` header value of `SAMEORIGIN`.

Because CodePen / JSFiddle show your test code in an iframe, clicking the link fails because it's attempting to load the link within that same iframe. Twitch's server prevents that from functioning.

The solution here is a) make the link open as a new window by [adding a `target` attribute of `_blank` or `_top` to the generated link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424505/passing-a-target-to-the-js-link-method) or b) do your development outside of CodePen/JSFiddle. It has nothing to do with `str.link` and is trivially debuggable by looking at your browser console - which should *always* be your very first step when working in JS.